# cl.exe(32bit) and cl.exe(64bit) have the same version, but why aren't they equivalent?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, cl.exe

This is the code written by a freshman student. I am checking out whether his code is wrong or right. And I found a wrong point. It is caused by a type-mismatch of parameters and arguments.

```
void make_data(FILE *fp,char,int n);
```

This is the prototype of a function. However he called the function with different arguments. Like this.

```
make_data(fin, "input.txt", 10);
```

The wrong point is obvious -- he declared the function prototype in wrong way. I first compiled this code with cl.exe(64bit) and executed the program. It was stopped in run-time.

However, when I compiled the same file with cl.exe(32bit), it didn't occurr a run-time error. Of course there were many compile warnings, but at least it was executed well at all. It seems that cl.exe(32bit)is more tolerant than the 64bit one. But they have the same version.(16.00.30319.01). Then why do they behave in different ways?

I understand that this is an undefined behavior. I know that Visual C compiler can be very different from gcc - because C language does not define all of details. What I want to know is why compiler in 32bit system and 64 bit system should be different like this.

Comment: Are you wondering why undefined behavior is undefined?

Comment: Think about the implications of **undefined** behaviour.

Comment: Not very clear what is the prototype and what the calling, but one of the reason that drives explosion on 64bits is the mismatch between pointer and other types size (like int). While on a 32 bits system pointers, integers, float, etc are 32bits wide, on a 64bits system they have different sizes influencing how parameters are passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show is valid C. It's nonsensical, but as far as C semantics go, it's valid and invokes no UB.

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void make_data(FILE *fp, char a, int n) {
   printf("%p %c %d\n", fp, a, n);
}

int main()
{
   FILE * fin = NULL;
   make_data(fin, "input.txt", 10);
}
```

Example output:

```
0x0 2 10
```

What you're not telling us, is that the declarations are different in different translation units. E.g. in `file1.c`, there's a `void make_data(FILE*, char, int);` declaration, and in `file2.c` there's a `void make_data(FILE*, char*, int) { ... }` definition. On a 64 bit system, the `char` and `char*` are passed in a different manner, and that causes the crash.

So, to reiterate, the problem is that you have not correctly identified the issue - in spite of it being completely preventable if you had only followed the directions. Please read and understand the [how to ask a good question page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). *It is on you and only on you to minimize the problem and be able to reproduce it before submitting a question.*